# Run python script without the "python" keyword

Tags: python, macos, terminal

How can I run a python script in Terminal on Mac without using the "python" keyword, without having to edit my existing python files?

Right now I have to do this:
`python script.py`

What I like to do is this:
`script.py`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add a shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

I prefer the second one, since Python can be anywhere like /usr/bin/python, /usr/local/bin/python etc. and second one ensure that you don't have to keep editing the shebang.

And then you can just execute it as `./script.py` if it is executable.

Comment: Will this trick work on the windows machine as well ?

Answer (score 15):

in your python script add this as your first line

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

then in terminal do this chmod +x ./yourpythonscript.py

then from terminal execute as ./yourpythonscript.py

Comment: @mofle nope sorry you can't make a file executable in unix system without specifying what file will execute it

Comment: I dont know about how but it might be possible on a Mac to associate an extension or a mime type to a handler (e.g. open all files of type .py with python) etc. Then you can do it without modifying your source files.

Comment: Actually, you can make a text file executable - but the system will then use your shell (probably bash) to execute it. Also, `#! /usr/bin/env python` is marginally more portable as it doesn't hardcode where python is.

Answer (score 6):

Try ./script.py instead of script.py ... or ensure your current directory is in your path and script.py should work....

Comment: thanks, this helped. I was trying to run with just script.py in the command line and it was giving me `command not found`.