# CLI app without python after install from pip

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I have seen a few examples of python packages that, after installing from something like pypi, have CLIs associated with the tooling.

Two examples:  **rasa** (e.g. `rasa init`) or **streamlit** (e.g. `streamlit hello`).

I am interested in exploring this for my own packages, with my requirement that I do not want to preface my commands with `python`.  For example, `rasa init` as shown above, not `python rasa init`, but admittedly I have no idea how this is happening under the hood.

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879869/run-python-script-without-the-python-keyword)?

Comment: Doesn't the shebang only apply to *nix?  If a windows user installed from pypi, would that still work and does it totally remove the need for the python prefix?  I don't know if it matters, but my question centers on the pip install of the package, and then it just works for the user, regardless of OS

Comment: I couldn't find a duplicate (and don't have the technical experience to write an answer), but I believe [this](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-stand-alone-command-line-tools/) is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Question: Are you trying to fully package it for `pip` installation? If so then you would want to specify the scripts as part of the package. The shebang is the start of making the script. Make sure the file is executable (e.g., `chmod +x` with git-bash)

Comment: Yes, my requirement that this ability occurs for a user after a pip installation.  The examples of rasa and streamlit above enable this functionality, it's just not obvious to me as to how it actually takes place

Comment: Do you have a `setup.py` in your repository?

Comment: My package can, yes.  I have a number of packages, I am trying to understand how to enable this generally.  I have been using flit lately which avoids the setup file, but I can always revert.  It is simply the presence of a setup.py file, or is it more to it than that?

Comment: @Btibert3 hopefully the below instructions is helpful to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`entry_points` or `scripts`](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#the-scripts-keyword-argument) are used for this.

Here's the relevant piece of `streamlit`'s `setup.py`:

```py
setuptools.setup(
    ...
    entry_points={"console_scripts": ["streamlit = streamlit.cli:main"]},
    ...
    # For Windows so that streamlit * commands work ie.
    # - streamlit version
    # - streamlit hello
    scripts=["bin/streamlit.cmd"],
)
```

- Here's explanation for `entry_points`: [Explain Python entry points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774824/explain-python-entry-points)
- Here's explanation for `scripts`: [Python setuptools using 'scripts' keyword in setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45114076/python-setuptools-using-scripts-keyword-in-setup-py)
- Here's a question about [Pros and cons of 'script' vs. 'entry_point' in Python command line scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23324353/pros-and-cons-of-script-vs-entry-point-in-python-command-line-scripts)

Interestingly, some sources seem to claim that `entry_points` doesn't work on Windows, while others claim that it is `scripts` that doesn't work on Windows. Personally I've always been using `entry_points` and it works for me both on Windows 10 and on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

This [guide](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) may be of help

Here's one of my simple [setup.py](https://github.com/astrochun/academic-ads-bibtex/blob/main/setup.py) to illustrate how I did it.

The `scripts=` option allow you to specify where the script(s) are. When you install it, then these scripts will be included in the paths allowing you to run them.

The scripts should be:

1. Executable `chmod +x`
2. Have a python shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python`
3. It is also best practices to have a `__name__` == `__main__` part of the code

To test it, you can build it and install it in a virtualenv

```
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel  # This will build the tar.gz (identical to what pypi uses)
virtualenv venv  # Create an env so you don't mess your setups
source venv/bin/activate  # Activate environment
pip install -e dist/<package_name>-<version>.tar.gz  # This installs it in the venv
```

`pip list` should show it's installed

If installation is successful your script should be available. On Mac, it's `which script_name`. The path will point to the `venv`.